# Can a SSIS package get corrupt after many changes and migrations?

Tags: ssis, bids

Can a SSIS package become corrupt after many changes and a migration (like a 'normal.dot' file)?? The reason why I ask this is because I see some very strange behaviour in the package.

**Background**
The SISS package was developed (by my predecessor) and running on SQL2005. I am in the process of (after some other adjustments) migrating it to SQL2008. One of the things the SSIS package does is importing 5 files into a database when the package runs. Over time the SSIS package performs many operations and as I am rather new to this, I am reluctant to start all over. The package is made in Business Intelligence Development Studio.

**Some of the Symptoms**

- On the (bigger and better) SQL2008, if a data-flow contains too many
  import tasks, it does not go through the debug. While the package did
  run on the older SQL2005 server. For that reason I have created a
  couple of smaller data-flows to import files.
- When the smaller data-flows (that import data) are placed in a
  sequence box, the debug runs perfectly. The package execution informs
  that the rows are inserted... but that does not happen for every
  table.
- Placing all the data-flows out of the sequence box reduces the tables
  that are not filled to only 1 table. Still the package execution
  informs that 35 rows are inserted. I double checked the source and
  destination.
- When using a data-conversion in the data-flow that does not work,
  another import data-flow gives a fatal error when the package is run.
  While neither the source file, or destination table are equal. And
  the data-flow tasks should be able to run independently.

My feelings starts telling me that after adjustmenst and a migration, the SSIS package is 'corrupt' of getting 'unstable to maintain'. But as I am new to this and rebuilding would take me (due to lack of skill) a lot of time, I first want to know for sure.. Can a SSIS package become 'corrupt' or unstable over time?

Comment: I find it hard to understand all the details of your problem but to answer the basic question, [code doesn't rust](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html).

Comment: You have the original package in 2005. It runs fine? You are converting the package to 2008 *plus* you are making procedural changes. I find that I have more success when I do not introduce that much change into a project. Convert the 2005 to 2008 and run it. Does it exhibit the same behaviour as the 2005? If so, check it into version control and only then would I start making logic changes to the package.

Comment: It seems that your desired state is to allow the package to load 5 files and each of those files is independent of each other - file 1 may exist, file 2 may not exist (or may fail to load) but there's no dependency on order of operations and the desire is for things to run regardless of success/failure of other loads. Is that about right?

Comment: No dependancies between either the tables or the files when those import-data-flows run. Yet they seem to have an effect on each others outcome. Code does indeed not rust, but as I make the SSIS package with "Business Intelligence Development Studio / BIDS", could it be that at time more "history" gets collected in the code while using BIDS and thus making the package instable for further development in BIDS? I perhaps also should add that at first the package was build in version 2005 of BIDS and the last part of the package building was done in version 2008 of BIDS.

Comment: I can read the SQL-code that BIDS produce and it is not always pretty. But I have no insight in the code that BIDS produce for the SSIS package. And as it is my first time I ever worked with a SISS package and lack either VB or C# skills and this being a one-time job, I do not think the customer will be happy with me first learning to program SSIS packages the decent way.

Comment: I asume the migration-step from 2005 to 2008 failed and thus giving illogical behaviour. I will try to do that step again tomorrow in a slightly different way and check the package. If not,.. rebuild :-(

Comment: If you think that is the case, then start a new SSIS project in 2008 and then import the 2005 project, not just the package. After converting a project, there should be an option to view the conversion log and it should list any issues encountered with it. Post some screenshots of what your control and data flows look like for the 2008 approach you feel is best. You may have to host offsite due to your lower rep level. My concern with rebuilding is that you may introduce the same error in your rebuild if the root cause is a design issue and not a conversion problem

Comment: Sorry for not giving an update. At the end two things turned out to be the problem. One of them was resolved after migrating the package a second time. The other problem was that the SSIS Package started a SQL-Job, but did not wait till that job was finished.

Being able to get a fatal error in one part of the program after tweeking another independent part was handled by the re-migration. And re-writing the SQL-Job part removed the chance that sometimes 1 or 2 tables (random out of 5 tables) were empty at the end.